# Is the Kalb-Ramond $B_{\mu\nu}$ equivalent to Kaluza-Klein $A_\mu$?

Tags: string-theory, kaluza-klein

The low-energy effective action of the [bosonic string](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) in the critical dimension $D=26$ can be written as:

$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa_0^2}\int d^{26}x\sqrt{-G} \left[ \phi^2\left( R-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda} \right) + 4\partial_\mu\phi \partial^\mu \phi\right].$$

which involves the dilaton field $\phi$, the metric $G_{\mu\nu}$ and the gauge-invariant field strength $H_{\mu\nu\lambda}=\partial_\mu B_{\nu\lambda}+\partial_\nu B_{\lambda \mu}+\partial_\lambda B_{\mu\nu}$.

As in [Kaluza-Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory), after compactification of the hidden dimensions, can the [Kalb-Ramond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalb%E2%80%93Ramond_field) field $B_{\mu\nu}$ be identified with the electromagnetic vector potential $A_\mu$?